# Windows Container Networking similar to 'internal: true'

Tags: docker-compose, docker-network, internals, windows-container

I want to use two service in docker-compose.yml: `frontend` and `backend`, the first one is nginx and the orther is an asp.net application, both based-on window images. `frontend` and `backend` must be on the same network which is marked as "internal" (so that `backend` can only communicate with the front), but front end can still access the internet. Howerver, in windows container the `internal: true` property as well as `bridge` network are not supported, how can i archive this?

the .yml file that should would on **linux container** but not on windows container:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  frontend:
    build: "./proxy"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "8080:4000"
    networks:
      - internal_network
      - out_network
  backend:
    build: "./webapp"
    expose: 
      - "80"
    networks:
      - internal_network
networks:
    internal_network:
      internal: true
    out_network: {}
```

Tried which orther network driver like l2bridge but still not succeed yet

Comment: Hi there, did you Google your question before posting it here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov of course, i did

Comment: @Community sorry, this is my first time asking here, is it more clear now

Comment: All Windows containers networks will invariably give the container access to the internet. To achieve this, you need to use a policy manager (Like Nginx). If your goal is to limit the ports open on the backend, you could try NAT, but you'll need to map which ports are open to the container, but you can't restrict who can get to that port, unless you use a policy manager - and the container will still have access to the web.